# How to close if statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Hi I have a problem if condition in for loop in vb.net look at my code

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "Admmission Fees" Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString, New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(250, 350))
        Else
            e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(250, 350))
        End If
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "Tearm Fees" Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString, New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(250, 375))
        Else
            e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(250, 375))
        End If

    Next
```

Here it is my loop and my condition now when my grid view has admmission fees as well as tearm fees it prints that value as well as 0.00 too can please give me the solution.

Comment: Your code is leaking GDI objects because you're not caching `Font` objects or disposing of them correctly, so your program will crash eventually.

Comment: You don't know how `If` statements work. It's not for us to teach you the basics of the language and programming in general.  Work through a beginners tutorial and learn how `If` statements work, particularly the `ElseIf` part.